# Suggesion on Active Directory Integration with Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I know there are many posts regarding Active Directory Integration but I am not here to ask the method to integrate(I already found), I just want to discuss is it possible to optimize my approach so here is the basic requirement:
I am working on MVC4 application and client just asked me to get all users of Active Directory to be saved in our UserProfile table and whenever a new user added to Active Directory it should be reflected to UserProfile table.

My Approach : I will build a scheduler to fetch the active directory users (using System.DirectoryServices namespace) and check the count of users in active directory and if it is increased then I'll add the new active directory user to my database.
Now I want to take a suggestion that is there any direct way to reflect the new Active Directory user in my sql server UserProfile table if this is possible then I don't need to create a scheduler and it will be more light weight process.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the count of the objects is not the way to go. Consider the case where a new user was added and another user was deleted. The count is still the same although some changes have happened that you need to obtain.

One way to do this is to use the [DirectorySynchronization class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysynchronization(v=vs.110).aspx). This class allows you to synchronize changes with active directory.

The first time you use it, it gives you all the objects that you want (based on some filter), and it also gives you a synchronization token. You then store that token into some storage. The next time you come to synchronize, you provide this class with token so that it knows what you currently have and only gives you the difference. Please see the example in the referenced MSDN reference.

There are some things you need to know about when using this API. I recommend that you read about it first. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677626(v=vs.85).aspx) contains some information that you need to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you so much.. one more question I have checked the link and they are strong sync cookie in a file and later industrialize it.. 1. If this cookie is persistent?(I mean I want to run a scheduler in every 30 mins) 2. If store this cookie value in Database will it work.

Comment: 1. Yes, you should store the cookie in a persistent store. And please note that each time you do the synchronization, the `DirectorySynchronization` class will give you a new cookie, you would need to store the latest cookie (and discard the old one). 2. Yes you can store it in the database. Please read the notes from the second reference I provided about what to store and where to store it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to schedule a procedure in sql server which updates your table if there are changes to active directory. You could use the unique key to join and merge the data and have it run daily, weekly, hourly, etc. This is currently what I am using for the same thing. It works great, there is no app needibg to run behind the scenes.